# Sql query to solve the below scenario

Tags: sql, database

I have a table like :

```
Employeeid personid reltnship status 
111        125        owner   active
111        252      prevown   active
112        3        descsd    active
```

I want to write a query to get all the details for the employees who have reltnship as combination of `'owner'`  and `'prevown'`

Comment: Please be more descriptive about your problem and add a sample output. Also try to show what you have tried before posting the question on the community. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to S/O, but your question is lacking some.  You have no context of an employee table or person table to get the respective person's name, and why would a given employee ID have two different person ID values.  Please edit question and provide additional data to GET the name information, or did you only want (in this case), the result of the two rows for employee ID = 111 (via legit query, not just for the employee ID)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Self JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.* 
FROM Tbl S JOIN tbl T ON S.Employeeid = T.Employeeid
where S.reltnship = 'owner' AND T.reltnship = 'prevown'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery that returns all the `employeeid`s that satisfy the condition:

```
select * from tablename
where employeeid in (
  select employeeid
  from tablename
  where reltnship in ('owner', 'prevown')
  group by employeeid
  having count(distinct reltnship) = 2
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uiuUuvNPTS9TN5BNveBaiy/0).
Results:

```
| Employeeid | personid | reltnship | status |
| ---------- | -------- | --------- | ------ |
| 111        | 125      | owner     | active |
| 111        | 252      | prevown   | active |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all details, then one method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.employeeid = t.employeeid and
                    t2.reltnship = 'owner'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.employeeid = t.employeeid and
                    t2.reltnship = 'prevown'
             ) ;
```

This is phrased to be index friendly.  The index that you want is on `(employeeid, reltnship)`.

If you only want the employees that meet this criteria, I would recommend aggregation:

```
select t.employeeid
from t
where reltnship in ('owner', 'prevown')
group by employeeid
having count(distinct reltnship) = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should study mysql query structure and what are clauses of queries.

Here is query:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where reltnship = 'owner'
or reltnship = 'prevown'
```

Comment: You completely missed the question being asked.  EMPLOYEES for Owner and PREVIOUS Owner, such as a sale of a home, car, etc... chain of ownership.   Who were the parties involved.